# CSS override / don't inherit

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a link in Wordpress quickly and we have a pretty complex style being applied to all a href links in the section. Here's a small sample of the selector and the styles within (there's about 40 lines of styles which I held back)

```
div.content-rotator li.featured-content a { 
    margin: 0px; 
    border: 1px solid rgb(34,56,19);
}
```

Is there anyway I can place a link in this li and override the parent style? It has to appear within the li with class featured-content.
I don't want to touch the existing CSS at this stage so I'd prefer to implement inline styles on the a element.

Thanks

EDIT: Just in case it wasn't clear, the CSS above is coming from the style sheet and I'd like to zero it out.
There's > 50 lines of styles in this though, I've only shown two for brevity so inline replacing them all isn't really an option.

Comment: Any inline styles will have higher precedence. So just try it and it will work.

Comment: @dfsq not entirely - an `!important` declaration in CSS *will* [override inline styles](http://jsfiddle.net/ma3rj0kp/). Not relevant for this question, but your comment is not factually complete.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes My comment was in regards to provided styles. They don't have `!important`. But of course you are right.

Comment: In addition to inline styles, you could play with selectors specificity. Setting an id on the link, for example, would override the defined styles because id selectors have higher specificity. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Although it doesn't help you now due to browser support, this would be a perfect usecase for web components. http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/

Answer (score 0):

Just use inline styles or/and add `!important` to overriden CSS definition, like:

```html
<div class="content-rotator">
    <ul>
        <li class="featured-content">
            <a href="#" style="margin: 3px !important; border: none !important;">...</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

or

```css
div.content-rotator li.featured-content a.other { 
    margin: 3px !important; 
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: The problem with inline styles is that there's like 50 styles right now specified in the style sheet which I'd have to override or set as zero, it's not as straight up as replacing those two.

Comment: Do you have to override those 50 styles? I don't think so, but even if you have to, you can still add class/id to `<a>` (above example uses `a.other`) and define all required styles for it in stylesheet. You can even use `<style>` to define it "inline" before rendering `<a>`, this is not good practice, but if you don't want touch stylesheets......

Answer (score 0):

Give the selected link an ID and just add !important to the styles. I don't think there is a better alternative unless you plan to go through the entire stylesheet.